# Обособление "того и гляди"

Tags: пунктуация

Требует ли выражение "того и гляди" обособления? В разных справочниках разные примеры.

Comment: Так дайте эти примеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обособление "того и гляди" возможно исключительно как авторское. 
Здесь смысл такой, что по основному правилу "того и гляди" не является вводным и не обособляться, но но может по контексту обособляться, если автор хочет придать тексту нужную интонацию.

У Розенталя:

> Он, того и гляди, нагрянет неожиданно (вводное сочетание, указывающее
>   на возможность внезапного действия)

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122

А вот мнение Редакции "Грамоты".

> В художественной литературе встречаются примеры обособления слов «того
>   и гляди»: Раньше спокойно можно было оставить автомобиль на улице, а
>   теперь, того и гляди, отвинтят что-нибудь, а то и вовсе угонят машину.
>   Н. Носов, Незнайка в Солнечном городе.
>
> Но всё же в большинстве случаев «того (и) гляди» не выделяется
>   запятыми. Вот примеры: Да разные дела на память в книгу вносим;
>   забудется того гляди. А. Грибоедов, Горе от ума. Вхожу к брату, он
>   сидит в постели, колени покрыты одеялом; постарел, располнел, обрюзг;
>   щеки, нос и губы тянутся вперед, – того и гляди хрюкнет в одеяло. А.
>   Чехов, Крыжовник. Молодость того и гляди пройдет, дожидаючись, да и в
>   Галицию угнать могут. Н. Берберова, Курсив мой. Дорога скверная, того
>   и гляди опоздаешь к поезду. А. Рекемчук, Время летних отпусков. Они
>   того и гляди в деревню пойдут. В. Распутин, Последний срок. Того и
>   гляди могло выглянуть солнце, пасть на деревню лучами, чтобы
>   увиделось, что натворил буран. В. Липатов, Деревенский детектив.

http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?p=227011&sid=3290a39e2fd330fa4f14036e3d8bbf53#p227011

По последней ссылке есть также небольшое обсуждение.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю Вамъ взять всё въ свои руки. Въ каждомъ отдѣльномъ случаѣ воля ваша.

> Да разные дела на память в книгу вносим; забудется того гляди.

А. Грибоедов, Горе от ума.

> Раньше спокойно можно было оставить автомобиль на улице, а теперь, того и гляди, отвинтят что-нибудь, а то и вовсе угонят машину.

Н. Носов, Незнайка в Солнечном городе.

Comment: Так вопрос же не Артём задавал...

Comment: @АлексейГригорьевич уберите реплику для Артема. Она непонятна читающему.

Answer (score -1):

ТОГО (И) ГЛЯДИ, частица

Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

*Да разные дела на память в книгу вносим; забудется **того гляди**.* А. Грибоедов, Горе от ума.
*Вхожу к брату, он сидит в постели, колени покрыты одеялом; постарел, располнел, обрюзг; щеки, нос и губы тянутся вперед, – **того и гляди** хрюкнет в одеяло.* А. Чехов, Крыжовник.
*Молодость **того и гляди** пройдет, дожидаючись, да и в Галицию угнать могут.* Н. Берберова, Курсив мой.
*Дорога скверная, **того и гляди** опоздаешь к поезду.* А. Рекемчук, Время летних отпусков.
*Они **того и гляди** в деревню пойдут.* В. Распутин, Последний срок.
***Того и гляди*** могло выглянуть солнце, пасть на деревню лучами, чтобы увиделось, что натворил буран. В. Липатов, Деревенский детектив.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_839